# Can I make videos on warframe gameplay?

Tags: warframe, legal

Can I make videos on warframe gameplay? I can't deduce it from the terms, I saw plenty out there though I am still no quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can do videos and nobody will close your channel.

But, if you're asking if you can make videos and monetize them via youtube, this might be kinda different. If you're going to take that road, I suggest you to open a ticket to Warframe support, so you can have official info and a written proof, if the need arises.

Comment: So I can't make videos but with no ads. Right?

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to monetize? plenty of people make a *living* on monetizing gaming videos.

Comment: I don't care about money lol

Comment: Actually, every company has it's policy. Asking official info is the best way, in my opinion.
@Rapitor actually, he can just do videos for fun.. that's how most youtubers started

Comment: Well you can always do videos of games on YT. Nobody is going to sue you for that (except if you were given a demo and signed some terms like 'not revealing it before the game is out').
But most of the time, you'll have a warning saying that you can't monetize that video because some contents belong to the game creator, or that it's going to be monetized but all the money will go the game creator and you can't say anything against that. But those are only warning, and overall, game creators are glad that people advertise their games on YT.